# Normalized Difference Built Up Indice with a threshold value in QGIS modeler

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler, binary

I want to use the modeler in QGIS, model the NDBI with a threshold value in order to produce a binary image. positive values = 1 and negative values = 0 
my question is about which tool I can use in the modeler to create the binary image?

Comment: Is there a reason you are trying to do this with the model builder instead of the more common raster calculator?

Comment: Yes, I want to keep a model in order to do this process in batch mode (use the iteration in model builder ) i have more than 20 Landsat images

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar [here](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/about/case_studies/australia_snowyhydro.html) where I created a binary grid for snow/non-snow then extracted the snow areas as a polygon.

You can see my model in the case study mentioned above, but basically I did the band math using the "r.mapcalculator" Grass tool (I renamed it "Create the NDSI grid") to give me my grid with the indexes. Then I used "r.recode" (renamed "Apply NDSI threshold") to create the binary grid based on my chosen threshold.

So your NDBI model would need two Raster inputs, which would be fed into the "r.mapcalutor", and the result of that would be fed into "r.recode" to create the binary grid based on your threshold.

Hope this helps and Good luck!